# How to get ActivityManagerService instance in Android app

Tags: android

I want to get a ActivityManagerService instance in my app(running in root uid), is it possible? How to do without xposed? Thanks

Comment: you mean `android.os.ServiceManager#getService()` method?

Comment: @pskink no, this will return `IActivityManager`, I want to get `ActivityManagerService`.

Comment: `ActivityManagerService` extends `ActivityManagerNative` which extends `Binder` and implements `IActivityManager`, so you want to get `IActivityManager` ?

Comment: sorry, no, I don't want `IBinder` client API,  I want to get server instance.

Comment: server instance what running in `system_server`

Comment: you cannot get any "server instance" running in different process - you can only get `Binder`

Comment: Oh... Is it possible when use root and set class loader?

Comment: Oh, too bad... Thank you